# How to have multiple condition on one column

Tags: mysql

I have table with students - name, id

and table with grades - id, grade value, discipline.

Each students has few grades. I want to select only the students with grade = 2 and grade = 6 in the same time.

```
SELECT NAME

FROM STUDENTS, GRADES 

WHERE STUDENTDS.ID = GRADES.ID 

AND GRADE = 2 AND GRADE = 6
```

The logical condition can't be valid there. Which is the function that I need?

Comment: Surely just using `OR` will work? Then the last line of your query becomes `AND (GRADE = 2 OR GRADE = 6)`, or shorter: `AND GRADE IN (2,6)`

Comment: Oh yes it worked, somehow I tried it before and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM STUDENTS s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GRADES WHERE ID = s.ID AND GRADE = 2)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GRADES WHERE ID = s.ID AND GRADE = 6)
```

or if you don't have multiple records for some grades for particular users:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM STUDENTS
JOIN GRADES ON STUDENTS.ID = GRADES.ID
WHERE GRADE = 2 OR GRADE = 6
GROUP BY ID, NAME
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```